# in python how to correct post request from curl

Tags: python, curl, post, python-requests, postman

I would like to make a post request from postman on python. As an example they give a curl. Heretheurl replaces the actual url.

curl --location 'https://heretheurl?jwt=token' 
--header 'Authorization: Bearer token' 
--header 'Accept: application/json' 
--form 'ids="164,1408453"'

My code looks like this so far:

```
ACCESS_TOKEN = 'hereaccesstokenstring'
data = {
    'ids': '164,1408453'
}
head = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(ACCESS_TOKEN),
    'Accept': 'application/json'
}
response = requests.post(f'http://heretheurl', headers=head, data=data)
```

I am getting the status code 405. Would anyone know what isn't correct with the post request? I am unsure whether I am giving the ids in the right form. The get request worked fine and that was given by:

curl --location 'http://heretheurl/1408453?jwt=token' 
--header 'accept: application/json'

```
head = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(ACCESS_TOKEN)}
response = requests.get(f'http://heretheurl/1408453', headers=head)
```

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: The value of the `ids` parameter in your cURL example is `"164,1408453"`, including those double quotes. In your python version, those quotes are missing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Tried with data = {
    'ids': '"111268,112239"'
} and unfortunately still error 405

Comment: 405 means Method Not Allowed. `--form` should make cURL send a POST request (which is what you are doing), but it also means the Content-Type will be `multipart/form-data`. So you might need to explicitly make your python code do that as well, right now it is probably sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, I suppose.

Comment: Do you know how to implement the multipart/form-data? I found that you should give a file so I tried with response = requests.post(f'http://heretheurl', headers=head, files=data)